# sudo write mode error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

i'm new in this "forum"
i have started few days ago with ubuntu server and i've got a weird error.
I write here the command string:

ubuntu@ubuntu: $ sudo -s
sudo: /var/lib/sudo/ubuntu/ is accessible in write mode from not-own (040777), should have modality 0700

I'm an italian guy and i've translated the error
This is the italian version:

sudo: /var/lib/sudo/ubuntu è accessibile in scrittura dal non-proprietario (040777) dovrebbe avere la modalità 0700

Someone can help me?
Thanks :)

Comment: You should try asking on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: That one is StackExchange's specialist Ubuntu forum. You may find someone on StackOverflow who can help, it may increase your chances of an answer by using the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be because of permisions on `/var/lib/sudo/ubuntu`, try changing them as the `sudo` expects (from root account):

```
chmod 0700 /var/lib/sudo/ubuntu
```

Comment: Thanks,but now i've another error ahhaha
sudo: /var/lib/sudo/ubuntu/tty1 is accessible in write mode from not-owner (0100777), should have 0600

Comment: You can change tis too:
chmod 0600 /var/lib/sudo/ubuntu/tty1
Actually, I think You can rename current /var/lib/sudo/ubunto to to /var/lib/sudo/ubunto_old and check if this folder is recreated with correct permisions.

Comment: The problem is disappear,i just rebooted my server
Anyway Thanks